# NSFetchedResultsController in Master-Detail application

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, master-detail

I'm trying to implement `NSFetchedResultsController` in my application. Currently I have a master table view and then when the user selects an item the detail view shows a collection view. The `collectionView` items will vary depending on the table view selected item.

I have a nice model that takes care of all of this. Basically a Presentation entity having a 1-to-n relationship with a Slide entity.

The way I do this now (before `NSFetchedResultsController`) is that I populate an `NSArray` with my presentations when the application starts, and then when the user selects a presentation on the master view I pass the relevant Presentation object to the collection view so it can show the slides. Pretty straightforward.

My question is how do I do that with an `NSFetchedResultsController`? Do I pass the entire `NSFetchedResultsController` object from master to detail along with some reference to the presentation so I can show the slides? Or do I only pass the Presentation object same as before? I'm still not comfortable with the inner workings of `NSFetchedResultsController` so I'd like to be sure I'm respecting best practices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass data as usual. If your `collectionView` needs `Presentation` object to populate itself, you can pass it.

Also, if you care about `NSManagedObjectContext` in which `Presentation` is, you can pass its `ManagedObjectId` and refetch it in `collectionViewController`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Somewhat unrelated (so might be better to make a different thread) but my `collectionView` seems to take an awful lot of time to reload the data (to display a border around the user selection). This is actually what triggered my question as I thought I might have been doing something wrong.

Comment: @DrunkenBeard I think, in that case performance problem lies on collection view part, not on FRC. So you can try to profile it with instuments to see what actually going on